# dd/cc command getting slow after custom mappings

Tags: neovim

I created below mappings for delete/change inner word for "/" and "," and the mappings work just fine, however the side effect is that it makes the normal dd/cc commands slow, almost approx by 1 sec. Below are my mappins

```
noremap ci/ f/cT/ 
noremap di/ f/dT/ 

noremap ci, f,cT, 
noremap di, f,dT,
```

And i kind of expected this because creating a mapping that starts with c/d which are already bound some other vim commands vim waits to check the key pressed after c/d. So what am i missing here, can this be fixed anyhow ?

Comment: You should probably check [`:h 'ttimeout'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27ttimeout%27), [`:h 'timeoutlen'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27timeoutlen%27) and [`:h 'ttimeoutlen'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27ttimeoutlen%27)

Comment: i tried setting the timeoutlen to 200, that decreases the delay for dd/cc but that breaks my custom mappings.

Comment: Why `noremap` instead of `nnoremap`?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble sorry about that, i guess that was just a mapping made in jiffy, but guess what it fixed that delay thing.. so thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the mapping from noremap to nnoremap and it worked for me.